# How to conditionally change color of markers in Plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `dataframe` in `R` that has some continuous values in column `value` and a `signal` column which is either 0 or 1.

```
db <- cbind(seq(1,5),rnorm(5,0,1), c(0,0,1,0,1))
colnames(db) <- c("ID","value","signal")
db <- as.data.frame(db)
```

Using `plotly`, I want to plot the line+markers of column `value` and have the marker of a different color from the line when the column `signal` has value of 1.

Anyone has any idea how to do this? The most I could get is a simple line+markers plot.

```
plot_ly(db) %>%
  add_trace(x=~ID, y=~value, type='scatter',
            mode='lines+markers', color=I('black'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the line plot and dot plot and decide color for them separately. You could try this,

```
plot_ly(db, x=~ID, y=~value, type='scatter',
        mode='markers', color = db$signal, 
        colors = c("1" = "white", "0" = "black")) %>%
  add_trace(x=~ID, y=~value, type='scatter',
            mode='lines', color=I('black'))
```